# Django Rest Framework hyperlink namespace improperly configured

Tags: python, django, rest, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I read a lot about problems affecting hyperlink on DRF when namespaces are used. But I didnt manage to resolve my problem by following the tips and recommandations on both Github and Stackoverflow so far.

I have recently added namespaces to my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                    # API
                    url(r'^api/', include(core_api_router.urls, namespace='api')),
                    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
                    url(r'^api-docs/', include('rest_framework_swagger.urls', namespace='api_docs'), name='api_docs'),
                   )
```

Here is my api.py

```
class MyBaseModelSerializer(DynamicModelSerializerMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):

    status = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, view_name='api:mybasemodel', read_only=True)

        class Meta:
            model = models.MyBaseModel
            fields = ('id', 'href', 'url', 'sid', 'name', 'status', 'created',)
            ordering_fields = '__all__'
            ordering = ('name',)

class ChangeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.MyBaseModel.objects.all().select_related('status')
    serializer_class = MyBaseModelSerializer

router.register('core/mybasemodel', MyBaseModelViewSet)


class MyRelatedModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    id = serializers.UUIDField(read_only=True)
    href = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='api:myrelatedmodel')

        class Meta:
            fields = ('id', 'href', 'key', 'comment', 'position', 'created')
            ordering_fields = '__all__'
            ordering = ('position',)

class MyRelatedViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.MyRelatedModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyRelatedSerializer

 router.register('core/myrelatedmodel', MyRelatedModelViewSet)
```

In my test I check whether I can modify an existing object via the API

```
def test_api_update(self):
    # Create an entry
    entry = self.Meta.factory.create()

    url = reverse('api:'+self.api_model_url+'-detail', args=[str(entry.id)])

    data = {'sid': 'Modified Entry'}

    # Check that an entry can be altered by an administrator via the API
    self.api_client.login(username='admin', password='admin')
    response = self.api_client.patch(url, data, format='json')
    content = self.parse_json_response(response, Status.HTTP_200_OK)
    self.assertEqual(content['sid'], 'Modified Entry')
```

Django raises this exception:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "mybasemodel-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
dmw.apps.core.views: ERROR: E500 : 127.0.0.1 : admin-user : http://testserver/api/core/api:mybasemodel/121e6850-3cd8-4795-d9bc-axsa04d1bd12/
```

My application runs on Python 3.4 with Django 1.8.9, Django Rest Framework 3.3.2 and I have tried with both:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
```

and

```
routeur = routeurs.SimpleRouter()
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Cheers!

Comment: It still doesn't work but I don't have the time to investigate further at the moment.. I'll accept your answer because it's a first step in the resolution of this problem! :)

Comment: It should work with both simple and default router right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem is in the `HyperlinkedIdentityField` of your two serializers `MyBaseModelSerializer` and `MyRelatedModelSerializer`. 
In `view_name` you have to specify the the full name, not only the basename like you did. From the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedidentityfield)

> view_name - The view name that should be used as the target of the relationship. If you're using the standard router classes this will be a string with the format -detail.

So you should add `-detail` there (like you do in your test):

```
# MyBaseModelSerializer
status = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, view_name='api:mybasemodel-detail', read_only=True)

# MyRelatedModelSerializer
href = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='api:myrelatedmodel-detail')
```

Answer (score 0):

Encountered Similar problem, Solved by correcting the fields in `serializer.py` . Check your fields corresponding to model fields. Any unmatched fields will produce this kind of error.

For Example my default Auth model has following fields:
(defaults fields from Django Auth Model after running migrations)

```
id, first_name , last_name, password, username,last_login, is_active, is_active, date_joined and email
```

what serializer does is: Pick up specified fields from your model , then convert it to json for API processing.

So this error raises if you order your serializer to pick up those fields which are certainly not present in your database of same model(table).

I hope it solves. :)